# Move values from JSON to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, morris.js

I'm trying to visualize data retrieved from a JSON file in a REST api. I'm using Morris js to create a simple bar chart. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to properly format the javascript array.

The chart is generated like this:

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'myfirstchart',
    data: [
        { year: '2008', value: 20 },
        { year: '2009', value: 10 },
        { year: '2010', value: 5 },
        { year: '2011', value: 5 },
        { year: '2012', value: 20 }
    ],
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    labels: ['Series A']
});
```

I have been trying to save values from JSON structure in a variable:

```
var USD = data.d.results[0].ExchangeCross;
var USD2 = data.d.results[0].ApprovedRate;
```

In order to add them to the chart i tried adding them to an array like this:

```
var obj = { year: USD, value: USD2 };
```

And then change `data:[]` to `data:obj`. This does not work. The optimal solution would be to run a `each` function for all the values i need, and then plot them into the chart.

Edit `forEach function`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://intra.site.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ExchangeRates?$orderby=Modified%20desc",
        headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
        success: function(data){ 
                    var params = {
                        element: 'myfirstchart',
                        data: [],
                        xkey: 'year',
                        ykeys: ['value'],
                        labels: ['Series A']
                                    };

                        var data = JSON.parse(data);

                        data.d.results.forEach(function(element) {
                        var obj = { "year": element.ExchangeCross, "value": element.ApprovedRate }; 
                        params.data.push(obj);
                    });

                    Morris.Bar(params);

                                }  
            });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load data received as JSON from API into your Morris chart. You do that by looping thru your JSON, creating an object and pushing those into an array.

Assuming that this is the JSON that you receive:

```
var jsonString = '{"d": {"results": [{"ExchangeCross": "2010", "ApprovedRate": "20"}, {"ExchangeCross": "2011", "ApprovedRate": "5"}, {"ExchangeCross": "2012", "ApprovedRate": "15"}, {"ExchangeCross": "2013", "ApprovedRate": "35"}, {"ExchangeCross": "2014", "ApprovedRate": "10"}]}}';
```

Create a params object to use with your Morris chart, with `data` as an empty array:

```
var params = {
    element: 'myfirstchart',
    data: [],
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    labels: ['Series A']
};
```

Parse your JSON (if you have a string):

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Iterate through the `results` array which is wrapped inside a `d`, create a compatible object with the values you need and push that object into the `params.data` array:

```
data.d.results.forEach(function(element) {
    var obj = { "year": element.ExchangeCross, "value": element.ApprovedRate }; 
    params.data.push(obj);
});
```

Call your `Morris.Bar` with `params`:

```
Morris.Bar(params);
```

.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'm not sure if the data is getting parsed correctly. I will edit the initial post to include your suggestions.

Comment: No no.. in that case just remove the line `var data = JSON.parse(data);`. Because you already have a parsed json at that point.

Comment: One last question. It seems that only every second `"year": element.ExchangeCross` is getting displayed. Any suggestions why?

Comment: By *"getting displayed"* if you mean the Morris chart.. then am sorry I have no idea on that. You will have to see the chart docs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you're trying to replace the `data` part of the JS object that you're passing to the Morris Bar function?

You need to create an array not an object.

Try something like this:

```
var USD = data.d.results[0].ExchangeCross;
var USD2 = data.d.results[0].ApprovedRate;

var dataArray = [];

// push each item into the array
dataArray.push( {year: USD, value: USD2} );

Morris.Bar({
    element: 'myfirstchart',
    data: dataArray,
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    labels: ['Series A']
});
```

Comment: Thx - exactly what I was looking for. What if i wanted to add multiple values? Would it be something like `dataArray.push( {year: USD, value: USD2}, {year: SGD, value: SGD2} )`?

Comment: `push` just adds a single element to an array. If you want to add multiple elements you can do that when you create the array. For example `dataArray= [ {year: USD, value: USD2}, {year: SGD, value: SGD2} ];`